# Are discrete random variables, with same domain and uniform probability, independent?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, self-learning, uniform-distribution

If X and Y are discrete random variables, both with domain {-1,0,1}, with uniform probability, does this imply they are independent? What would be the expected value E(XY) and probability like P(XY=1) or P(XY=-1) in this case?

Comment: Not necessarily : the point is that independence is a *joint* property of two random variables, and can never be deduced from the individual random variables' distributions alone. For example, if I take $X=Y$ to be uniform on that domain, then it's clear that $X,Y$ aren't independent (at least in the sense of what independence means), and $E[XY]$ and so on will have to be calculated from the formulas for expectation (and not through independence-related shortcuts).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you @TeresaLisbon!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon how about their correlation? Is Corr(X,Y) always equal to -1, 1, or 0 in this case?

Comment: That's a more interesting question (if you allow $X,Y$ to be dependent). My guess is no, because I see that $X,Y$ can vary at three points and it looks possible to me that this much should be enough to give some non-zero non-$1/-1$ correlations. I could be wrong, but that's a great question.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17868/if-random-variables-are-drawn-from-an-identical-distribution-why-doesnt-this-g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does this imply they are independent?

No! To get independence you have to use the corresponding definition:

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)$$

$\forall (x,y)$

In your case you do not have enough information to conclude for independence. You need, for example, their joint distribution.

Here are two examples with the same uniform marginals which are independent (example 1) and not independent (example 2)

[image]

---

To calculate correlation coefficient, first calculate covariance

$$\text{Cov}[X,Y]=\mathbb{E}][XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]=\Sigma_i\Sigma_j XiY_i p(x_i,y_j)-0=$$

$$=-1\cdot(-1)\cdot\frac{1}{6}+(-1)\cdot0\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\dots=\frac{1}{6}$$

thus

$$\rho_{XY}=\frac{\frac{1}{6}}{\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks, @tommik! Can we comment anything on the correlation between such variables? Is it always going to be 1, -1, or 0?

Comment: @Sam : in the first example, being them independent their correlation is zero. In the second case you have to calculate by using the definition. Start with calculating their covariance: $E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$. Are you able to do that or you do need help?

Comment: that's the covariance, right? I am not sure how to calculate E(XY) there. Kindly help me with that. Thanks!

Comment: @Sam : edited answer with all details. Hope now it is clear